# Back Button with strange behaviour on fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here's my navigation:

`HomeFragment -> LoginFragment -> CreateEventFragment`

My `HomeFragment` is my first Fragment inside my `MainActivity`.

In my code, I'm replacing each one of them using the same view `id`( a `FrameLayout` inside my `MainActivity`'s layout: `R.id.container`).

So every `replace()` is being called like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = mContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .replace(containerId, nextFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Except for `LoginFragment` to `CreateEventFragment`, because after the user logs in, he doesn't have to go back to `LoginFragment` so I don't call `addToBackStack()`.

But something strange is happening: 
When I'm on `CreateEventFragment`, after logging in successfully, and press the back button, my `CreateEventFragment` `onDestroy()` is not being called.

Debugging it I noticed that it isn't removed from the `backStack`, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Some code:

Common replace fragment method, inside `BaseFragment`, parent class of all three `Fragment`s

```
public void replaceFragment(int containerId, Fragment nextFragment, boolean addToBackStack){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = mContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (addToBackStack)
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .replace(containerId, nextFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    else
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .replace(containerId, nextFragment).commit();
}
```

On `HomeFragment`:

```
BaseFragment nextFragment =
            (PreferencesHandler.isLogged()) ?
                CreateEventFragment.newInstance() :
                LoginFragment.newInstance("create_event") ;
replaceFragment(R.id.main_fragment_container, nextFragment, true);
```

On `LoginFragment`:

```
public void goToNextFragment(){
    Fragment nextFragment;
    switch (mIntent){
        case "create_event":
            nextFragment = new CreateEventFragment();
            break;
        case "participate":
            nextFragment = new ListsFragment();
            break;
        default:
            nextFragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
    }
    replaceFragment(R.id.main_fragment_container, nextFragment, false);
}
```

My `MainActivity`'s layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            />

        <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:name="Fragments.`NavigationDrawerFragment`"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT 2**

Noticed that pressing back button calls `LoginFragment` `onDestroy`, but not `CreateFragment`'s. Also noticed that backStack has `LoginFragment`, guess it shouldn't, right?

Comment: Have you overriden your onBack to perform the backstack.pop?

Comment: No, not even `onBackPressed()` in my activity...

Comment: But should I override it?

Comment: If you don't want it in the back stack then don't use `.addToBackStack(null)` when you are doing the replace.

Comment: That's what I am saying on my question. The problem is that after pressing back on `CreateEventFragment`, it is not being destroyed

Comment: Are you by any chance calling `setRetainInstance(true)` in `CreateEventFragment` ?

Comment: No... this is very strange because if I add my `LoginFragment` to the back stack, everything works fine...

Comment: The issue is somewhere in details you omitted in the question. You should really share the code.

Comment: Try fragmentmanager.executependingtransactions() after replace

Comment: Placed inside my `CreateEventFragment`'s `onCreateView()` and got  `Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions`

Comment: Fragment based navigation is so broken it's not even funny anymore. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Didn't understand. You mean the concept of fragment navigation?

Comment: Have your common replace fragment in your activity , dont handle it from the fragment .